# How to setup a shortcut for UV Editor's selection modes?

Tags: interface, shortcut

I would imagine it would be something like this, but this, and similar, does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your in the wrong area. 2DView is general navigation for flat area types.

The UV/Image editor shortcuts are under Image -> UV Editor

[image]

Also for the value you will need to make it a string by using quotes.

[image]